# ObjectDataSource used outside gridview, not passing start, page size or sortby

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an existing ObjectDataSource bound with a GridView that produces an html representation of the data.  The requirement came in to add buttons for different output types (pdf, excel, etc), so I thought Great, I'll use the same data source to consolidate all of the filtering parameters, then I'll just call ObjectDataSource.Select() to get the data set and run through different routines to do the output.

For the most part, it works, but for some reason the parameters that I set in OnSelecting for the sort expression, start index and page size don't get passed through to the selection method.

To put some examples on it, the data source looks like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetUsers"
    EnableCaching="false" TypeName="App.UserManager"
    EnablePaging="True" SelectCountMethod="GetUsersByParamCount"
    OnSelecting="SetFilterInputs" SortParameterName="sortedBy" />
```

(Page size and start index parameter names default to maximumRows and startRowIndex respectively).  In my OnSelecting method, I have

```
if ((object)ButtonClicked == (object)GeneratePdfButton)
{
    inputParams.Add("startRowIndex", 0);
    inputParams.Add("maximumRows", UserGridView.PageSize);
}
```

Then the actual button click method has

```
if ((object)ButtonClicked == (object)GeneratePdfReportButton)
{
    IEnumerable<UserItem> results = (IEnumerable<UserItem>)ObjectDataSource1.Select();
    ... go create pdf output from the data set.
```

I've stepped through my OnSelecting method, and the start index and page size values **are** being set, but when ObjectDataSource1.Select() ends up at the SelectMethod, all the filter inputs are set properly, except startRowIndex, maximumRows, and sortedBy - those come in as 0, 0, and "" respectively.

I've read a bunch of posts about data source configuration and parameter passing.  Some say that the gridview values will override the default values you declare.

But I didn't see anything about calling ObjectDataSource.Select() directly or why those parameters (even though set in the e.InputParameters of the OnSelecting method) would be separately dropped.  Like I said, all of the other filter parameters are getting passed properly - just the default paging params are not.

I did double-check that the ObjectDataSource.EnablePaging = true

Does anyone have any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Okay, I've been digging into this, and it appears while the documentation implies ObjectDataSource.Select() can be used independently it's really not fully.  Using Reflector, I found values for sortedBy, startRowIndex, and maximumRows in your SelectParameters collection are effectively ignored in favor of those settings on whatever binding container (if any) you are using.  If you don't have a binding container, and call .Select() directly then ObjectDataSourceView is created with a stub DataSourceArguments with all those empty, and the empty values blow away whatever was in your collection.

Comment: Doing some more digging, I found a few posts (including a blog entry by Rick Stahl) suggesting ways of getting at it via an OnRowCommand handler where you go to ((DataTable)GridView.DataSource).Rows.  But a) this is using the Sql data source, not the ObjectDataSource, b) it appears to rely on it being a postback action from rendered results.  I tried using OnRowDataBound to do the same thing, and GridView.DataSource was always null.  Don't know if that was because of the event I chose or the more generic ObjectDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's a bit of a kludge, but we had a lot of code already ginned up to process all of our custom filters which is why I didn't want it to go to waste.

See the comments above for what I found out about ObjectDataSource.Select() and how/why {sort expression, start index, and page size} get blown away when you call it directly.

The quick and (very) dirty way to get to use ObjectDataSource.Select() directly for other output formats was to add 2 red-herring parameters (in my case, I wanted the start index to be 0 on the other output formats).

When the other output format buttons are clicked, I rename the sort expression and page size parameter names on the ObjectDataSource to the red herrings (say SortX and MaxX) and fill in the regular ones as usual.  The stub ObjectDataSourceView will add the red herrings to the parameter list

If it's the html output, bound to a gridview, then I add the red herring parameters to the collection myself so things stay balanced.

So now I can use the ObjectDataSource directly to drive all of the other, non bindable container output formats.